Fantasy novel by woman author, featuring a male eunuch and a runaway girl
I believe the author's name is Rachel. A young girl flees her home, is mistreated on her travels, and is rescued by a eunuch in another city. They both become important political players.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Does this take place in a fantasy world?  What are the fantasy elements of the story?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/fantasy-fiction-book-using-titles-ethnarch-majordomo-dynast-tetrach?

Sounds a bit like Wilbur Smith's River God in his Ancient Egypt series. I don't remember the young girl being mistreated, but she is owned as slave by a powerful eunuch in the Pharaoh's service and becomes a political figure IIRC.

Longshot, but Empress, by Karen Miller, fits the vague shape.  Any more detail you could add would help

This is a list of all novels on IFSDB with "Rachel" in the author's name. But it's a long list!

I suspect we'll need more details to identify the book.
